# Offset and stride

Tags: c++, opengl

can someone please explain what is wrong here. Guess it is something with offset and stride but...

```
glBindVertexBuffer(0, m_vboID, 0, sizeof(float) * 2);
glBindVertexBuffer(1, m_vboID, offsetof(Vertex, color), sizeof(GLubyte) * 4);
glBindVertexBuffer(2, m_vboID, offsetof(Vertex, tex), sizeof(float) * 2);

glVertexAttribFormat(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex));
glVertexAttribBinding(0, 0);

glVertexAttribFormat(1, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, sizeof(Vertex));
glVertexAttribBinding(1, 1);

glVertexAttribFormat(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex));
glVertexAttribBinding(2, 2);
```

Vertex holds Position struct with 2floats, Color struct with 4 GLubyte and Tex struct with 2 floats.

If i replace that with this code, it is working good.

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, position));
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, color));
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, tex));
```

Comment: _strid_ is the distance between elements within the buffer. If you have a buffer where each vertex attribute tuple contains 8 components, 4  type float and 4 of type byte, e.g. (x, y, r, g, b, a, u, v), stride is `4*sizeof(float) + 4*sizeof(GLubyte)` (for all 3 attrbibutes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*stride* is the distance between elements within the buffer. If you have a buffer in which each vertex attribute tuple contains 8 components, 4 of type *float* and 4 of type *ubyte*, e.g. (x, y, r, g, b, a, u, v), stride is `4*sizeof(float) + 4*sizeof(GLubyte)` (respectively `sizeof(Vertex)`):

```cpp
GLsizei stride = 4*sizeof(float) + 4*sizeof(GLubyte);
glBindVertexBuffer(0, m_vboID, 0, stride);
glBindVertexBuffer(1, m_vboID, offsetof(Vertex, color), stride);
glBindVertexBuffer(2, m_vboID, offsetof(Vertex, tex), stride);
```